# How to backup postgresql database of rails project deploy on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, backup, capistrano

I need to backup postegresql database of rails project deployed on EC2 using Capistrano. So how can i do that and also i want to save backup data on my local computer

Comment: If capistrano has no backup support build in you will have to use one of the standard ways. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/backup.html you are probably best of starting with SQL dumps. When your database grows large it will be worth investing time in one of the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to find where you PG data located:
run:

```
ps aux | grep postgres | grep -- -D
or
ps ax | grep postgres | grep -v postgres
```

than zip this folder(for example /var/postgres/9.5/data i have no idea where is on your server)
run:

```
sudo zip -r ~/9_5_postgres.zip /var/postgres/9.5/data
```

download it on local machine

```
scp server-user-name@ip-address:~/9_5_postgres.zip ~/
```

unzip it

```
unzip ~/9_5_postgres.zip
```

probably folder unzipped in ~/var/postgres/9.5/data user folder 
and then run postgres server(stop postgres before and use stop/start/restart in the end):

```
pg_ctl -D ~/var/postgres/9.5/data -l ~/var/postgres/9.5/pg.log start
```

Use in your config/database.yml same password login as in production
and chine on prod if you commit you config/database.yml in git